# Select the min(ID), number where every number has multiple IDs and also display data for same (min) ID from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that contain common ID for every number. 
table1 contains only 1 row with the number for every ID.  Based on this number and the respective ID, I wanted to find at table2 the minimum ID and display this unique ID for every number (of 1st table).
table2 contains multiple IDs (for number of table1).

After advice from MT0, the working SQL for this is:

```
SELECT MIN( t2.ID ) AS min_id,
   t1.number 
FROM   table1 t1
   INNER JOIN
   table2 t1
   ON ( t2.ID = t1.ID )
WHERE  t1.number in (<list of comma separated numbers>)
GROUP BY t1.number;
```

Now, I also want to get (select) related data (text) from a table3, where t3.ID=t1.ID=MIN(t2.ID).

When I try to do so with:

```
SELECT MIN( t2.ID ) AS min_id, t3.data, t1.number 
FROM  table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
    table2 t1
    ON ( t2.ID = t1.ID )
    LEFT JOIN
    table3 t3
    on ( t3.ID = t1.ID )
WHERE  t1.number in (<list of comma separated numbers>)
GROUP BY t1.number;
```

I get error that "not a GROUP BY expression" for the t3.data.
What am I doing (thinking) wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your logic is hard to follow.  You seem to name most of the columns `id`, but that is not correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Out of curiosity, why do you say that's not correct?

Comment: @Boneist . . . In `t1`, `number` and `id` are both unique (according to the text).  In `t2`, `t2.id` is the same as `t1.id`.  So, the `min()` is not really taking the min of anything.  The query would be clearer by using `group by t1.number, t1.id` and including `t1.id` in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is hard to follow.  Based on the text (not the sample code), I assume the join key between `t1` and `t2` is `number`, not `id`.

One approach uses aggregation in a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.number, t3.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t2.number, MIN(t2.id) as minid
      FROM table2 t2
      GROUP BY t2.number
     ) t2
     ON t2.number = t1.ID INNER JOIN
     t3
     ON t3.t2id = t2.minid
WHERE t1.number in (<list of comma separated numbers>);
```

Actually, as phrased, `t1` is not necessary:

```
SELECT t2.number, t3.*
FROM (SELECT t2.number, MIN(t2.id) as minid
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.number in (<list of comma separated numbers>)
      GROUP BY t2.number
     ) t2
     t3
     ON t3.t2id = t2.minid;
```

Comment: The t3.data is for the number, but number can have many t3.data based on the t3.ID and t3.ID=t1.ID=min(t2.ID).